# Find callers in maven project, not Imported in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a couple of modules of a maven project imported in eclipse. 
Let's say I want to find all callers of the method, `Foo.calculate()`. 
We normally do a Cntl + ALT + H. But this only works on modules that are already imported. 
How can I get eclipse to refer all modules in the main pom, to list all callers of the method `Foo.calculate()`?

Comment: I doubt that this is possible.

Comment: Eclipse is only aware of what's happening within the current workspace, that's why I don't think you can find a solution.